# OWIN Cookies vs FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

Are there any major advantages of using OWIN cookie-based authentication over Forms Authentication cookie-based authentication for developing MVC web applications?

The reason I ask is that I would not be using any of the Entity Framework based hooks for OWIN authentication. I've built apps based on Forms Authentication for years and have been able to do things like create different authentication tokens for admins (faster timeouts), anonymous users, and registered users. Using the UserData portion of the ticket I was able to implement universal sign out, store custom properties, etc.

One of the advantages to OWIN might be testability, but I'm not sure. The ClaimsIdentity is kind of nice  because I can easily store and access custom fields without having to serialize/deserialize the properties into UserData. Other things I should consider?

Comment: This has nothing to do with OWIN.. this is asp.net identity, which just so happens to have also moved to the owin layer in the default template, but can also be used elsewhere.  OWIN is just a middleware abstraction layer.  One you should probably adopt early because the next version of Visual Studio will be heavily dependent upon it because System.Web dependence is being phased out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cookie authentication middleware can run in any OWIN host including IIS, whereas FormsAuthenticationModule can run only in IIS+ASP.NET. If you have a present or future need for hosting in different types of hosts, CAM is a better option. Another feature middleware has but not FAM is, the cookie chunking. If your user data is big enough for the cookie to be over the allowed size limit, browsers simply stop sending the authentication cookie whereas the middleware chunks big cookies into multiple small cookies and reassembles them on receipt.

Comment: To expand on this, ASP.NET is moving towards a model that is less dependent upon the server that is used.  Staying with FormsAuth ties you to IIS, which you may not care about today, but one day you'll have a lot of work to do to fix all this... better to adopt the new method now when its easy, since this is the way it will be moving forward.